# twitter sentiment analysis Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)

Tags: r, twitter, analysis, rcurl

I want to analyze tweets. I am using this code.
https://analytics4all.org/2016/11/25/r-twitter-sentiment-analysis/

The problem is that when I execute this line:
tweets = searchTwitter('Paris',n=500)

I get this error:
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't connect to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by wrong information in your Twitter authentication block, looking at the code on that page. The code from the page you gave worked for me, so double check your API key, API secret, access token, and access token secret are entered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple message saying that you weren't allowed to access the server.

Have you tried several times? The Twitter API has a rate limit: you can only make 1500 request by 15 minutes on the REST API.

If not, you should check that you've input the good api keys and secret.

Best,

Colin